# send email with VBA with no user interaction with email client

Tags: email, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to get this code to send the attachment via email. But their will be several hundred attachments, so i don't want the user to need to interact with the email client. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Private Sub CreateReports_Click()

```
Dim x           As String
Dim y           As String
Dim StrSQL      As String
Dim stWhereStr  As String 'Where Condition'
Dim stSection   As String 'Selection from drop down list
Dim stfile      As String
Dim stDocName   As String
Dim StrEmail    As String

StrSQL = "SELECT DISTINCTROW [OPDA ISSR- Courts Users by District/Cir].[Sup], [OPDA ISSR- Courts Users by District/Cir].SupEmail " & _
    "FROM [OPDA ISSR- Courts Users by District/Cir];"
y = Year(Date)


Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim qdTemp As DAO.QueryDef
Set qdTemp = db.CreateQueryDef("", StrSQL)
Set rst = qdTemp.OpenRecordset()
If rst.EOF And rst.BOF Then
    MsgBox "No data available for the Ledger Process routine."
Else
    Debug.Print rst.Fields.Count
    rst.MoveFirst
    Do While Not rst.EOF
    x = rst![Sup]
    StrEmail = rst![Supemail]

    stDocName = "Courts - ISSR Recertification Report"
    stWhereStr = "[OPDA ISSR- Courts Users by District/Cir].[SUP]= '" & x & "'"
    stfile = "P:\DFI\FIB\Access Tables\FibCustomers\ISSR Reports\Courts\" & x & " - " & y & " FedInvest InvestOne Recertification.pdf"

    DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acPreview, , stWhereStr
    DoCmd.SendObject acSendReport, stDocName, acFormatPDF, StrEmail, , , "My Subject here", "your report"
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, stDocName, acFormatPDF, stfile
    DoCmd.Close acReport, stDocName

    rst.MoveNext
Loop
End If
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Will this help. It gives two examples .. [MS Access send email](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa167323(v=office.11).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You could either use your local email client's API and open a hidden instance to create and send emails (e.g. Outlook, Lotus Notes) or you could use the CDO object.

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/cdo.htm

Even though the above example is in Excel, the code works great.  The only thing you will have to make sure if you're using the CDO object is if the necessary ports are open.  Also check the related threads to this question, tons of valid information if you want to go with a specific email client.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to send unattended emails is to use SMTP. Bypassing the MAPI security prompts is not a good idea.

Our Total Access Emailer addin program uses SMTP so you can broadcast a large volume of emails for your users. Total Access Emailer lets you send personalized emails to everyone on your list and embed fields from your records in the message and subject. It can also attach Access reports as PDF files filtered for each recipient so that each person only sees their data. No programming is required with its Wizard interface. A VBA library is available if you want to automate it. More info here: http://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/Email.asp

A free trial is available: http://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/Email/free-trial.html